# Porting shell functions to cmd.exe: Is it possible to automatically source scripts on startup?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, shell, cmd

I'm porting a Linux tool-set that makes frequent use of shell functions to provide certain functionality. These functions are automatically sourced when you start a new shell and include things like changing the working directory, which is nigh impossible with stand-alone programs because child processes can't change their parent's environment.

For example, there is a function `cdbm` which changes the working directory to one that was previously bookmarked. Now I want to do the same on Windows, but I'm stuck with `cmd.exe`. As far as I understand the scripts could be ported to jscript, vbscript or plain batch, which shouldn't be a problem. But how do I make sure they automatically get sourced on startup and live in the shell's environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `help cmd`:

```
If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
either or both are present, they are executed first.

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

        and/or

    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

As a test, in `regedit` I created a new key in the HLM branch shown above called "AutoRun" with the string value "echo Hi". When I started a new instance of `cmd` I got:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6000]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Hi

C:\Users\Username>
```

You could put in the name of a script to run instead (I would put in a fully specified path to the script or one with a environment variable in it like "%HOMEPATH%\scripts\scriptname" (including the quotes in case there are spaces in the name).

**Edit:**
The registry key has some side effects. One example is `help`. If I have the `echo` command above, for example, in the AutoRun when I type `help vol` I get a "Hi" right above the help text. Doing `vol /?`, though doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set either of the following registry keys to a batch file or other executable to run that program when `CMD` is started:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

A batch file should be able to change the current directory of the executing `CMD` process with the `CD` command, as it doesn't run as a subprocess.  You can disable the autorun behaviour by supplying `/D` as a switch to `CMD`.

See `CMD /?` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since `cmd` doesn't allow you to define functions in global scope, I'm a little at a loss to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve by auto-sourcing a script at startup. I tend to include a batch file directory in my path where you can put batch files I regularly need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: I know about cygwin but it's not really an option at this moment. The tools already work there but I want to provide the same functionality to Windows users without the need to install a POSIX layer, if that is possible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rostyslav: The answer was to look at cygwin, the link was just an additional bonus.